# Best way to re-initialize user login with PHP Cookie

Tags: php

I have built a semi-basic user system that is using session to check whether or not the user is logged in. Now, I want to create a remember me checkbox to create a cookie that will delete its self in a year or 2. I have created that part, but what is the best way to use that cookie to keep the user logged in?

I know the session will eventually dissapear, so what is the best way to stop that from happening with my cookie.. I only store the username in the cookie and no passwords. Also, what is a good way to stop people from editing their cookie to 'fool' the system in to thinking it is their account... Currently this is my function to check if the user is logged in:

```
public function isloggedin()
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['user']))
    {
        return true;
    } else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and this is how I am generating the cookie:

```
setcookie("XE_RememberMe", $username, time()+ 10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60,'/');
```

Also, what are some good practices for cookies?

Answer (score 0):

After user login, create unique session id and push this id to table `sessions_id`(which relative to `users` table) and push same id to cookie. Further, compare cookie id with table `sessions_id`.

Answer (score 0):

If having the username stored in a cookie is the only criteria for logging a user in then anyone can either create or update a cookie to login as any arbitrary user.

What you need is a nonce:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce

When a user logs in generate a nonce and store it in a cookie (along with the username) as well as the user database.

The cookie 'login' process would then be:

1. Gather the username and nonce from the cookie.
2. See if a user exists with that username and nonce.
3. If the user exists log them
4. Generate a new nonce and store it in the database and update their cookie.

A nonce should be unique to each user and it can only be used once.

Generating a nonce is fairly easy, it just needs to be a random string that cannot be predicted. You could just use uniqid() or hash() with a random input.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php